# SQL query which can convert Rows in to Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

| RuModules_Id | Info |
| --- | --- |
| 9 | 1,1,49 |
| 16 | 1,0,50 |
| 16 | 2,0,51 |
| 16 | 3,0,52 |
| 16 | 4,0,53 |
| 17 | 1,0,54 |
| 17 | 2,0,55 |
| 17 | 3,0,56 |
| 17 | 4,0,57 |
| 18 | 1,0,58 |

I need to convert the Table A to Table B. Can someone help me how to do it in SQL query?

[image]

Comment: Please, post your sample data and expected results as text. If you have fixed number of `M` columns, conditional aggregation or pivoting the table are possible solutions.

Comment: You can't have arbitrary columns in a relational database, either in a table or a query. You'll have to do this on the client. A table is the actual R(elation) in RDBMS, not the foreign key *constraint*. A table specifies the relation between values. You can't have arbitrary relations.  The PIVOT and UNPIVOT commands actually need to know the "column" values in advance

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? Why do you want this? Transposing data is best done on the client. Displaying horizontal instead of vertical grids is a UI concern. It's far easier to create a "horizontal" table in HTML than try to come up with a SQL query

Comment: Do you know the maximum number of columns?

Comment: @kendle yes We have 4 columns

Comment: Ok please post your data a text. A DBfiddle would be perfect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 3):

Possible approaches are conditional aggregtaion and PIVOT relational operator. You need to number the rows and group them appropriately (even if you have more than 4 rows for each `RuModules_Id`):

Statement with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
   RuModules_Id,
   M1 = MAX(CASE WHEN RN % 4 = 0 THEN Info END),
   M2 = MAX(CASE WHEN RN % 4 = 1 THEN Info END),
   M3 = MAX(CASE WHEN RN % 4 = 1 THEN Info END),
   M4 = MAX(CASE WHEN RN % 4 = 2 THEN Info END)
FROM (
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RuModules_Id ORDER BY Info) - 1 AS Rn
   FROM Data
) t 
GROUP BY RuModules_Id, Rn / 4
```

Statement with PIVOT:

```
SELECT RuModules_Id, M1, M2, M3, M4
FROM (
   SELECT 
      (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RuModules_Id ORDER BY Info) - 1) / 4 AS Id,
      *, 
      CASE (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RuModules_Id ORDER BY Info) - 1) % 4
         WHEN 0 THEN 'M1'
         WHEN 1 THEN 'M2'
         WHEN 2 THEN 'M3'
         WHEN 3 THEN 'M4'
      END AS M
   FROM Data
) t
PIVOT (  
   MAX(Info)  
   FOR M IN ([M1], [M2], [M3], [M4])  
) p
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which SQL database you are using.

Also, your table A is missing a column containing "M1", "M2" etc. In my solution below, I expect the data structure to be:

```
ModuleId | RuModules_Id | Info
M1 | 9 | 1,1,49
```

If you are using SQL Server, you *can* do a pivot.

The syntax would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    [ModuleId]
    [RuModules_Id],
    [Info]
  FROM A
) A_sub
PIVOT (
  MAX([Info])
  FOR [ModuleId]
  IN (
    [M1],
    [M2],
    [M3],
    [M4]
  )
) AS PivotTable
```

In the example above (not tested), it would build the columns M1,M2,M3,M4 add a row for each unique value found in RuModules_Id and in each sell the max value found in [Info] for the specific combo of ModuleId and RuModules_Id would be listed.

It is not possible to do a dynamic solution with raw SQL. You need to know which exact columns you create (in our example we created M1, M2, M3, M4.
*M5 and above will not be included in the result.*

If you want it to be dynamic, you can write a stored procedure (if using MS SQL server for example), that generates a query based on some input. The string "[M1],[M2],[M3],[M4]" would then be the input. The stored procedure could then be used in another stored procedure, that builds the list of colums.